# If $a,b,c > 0$ prove $\frac{(b+c-a)^2}{a}+\frac{(a+c-b)^2}{b}+\frac{(a+b-c)^2}{c}\ge\frac{b^2+c^2}{b+c}+\frac{a^2+c^2}{a+c}+\frac{a^2+b^2}{a+b}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

$a,b,c > 0$
$$\frac{(b+c-a)^2}{a}+\frac{(a+c-b)^2}{b}+\frac{(a+b-c)^2}{c}\ge\frac{b^2+c^2}{b+c}+\frac{a^2+c^2}{a+c}+\frac{a^2+b^2}{a+b}$$

I have used Tittu here with the second and the third fraction and came with this result :

$$\frac{(a+c-b)^2}{b}+\frac{(a+b-c)^2}{c}\ge\frac{(a+c-b+a+b-c)^2}{b+c}=\frac{4a^2}{b+c}$$

If you do this (taking fractions two by two) then you have to divide them by 2 in order to get the LHS and thus :
$$LHS \ge \frac{2a^2}{b+c}+\frac{2b^2}{a+c}+\frac{2c^2}{a+b}$$

I believe I am quite near solving this but I can't come up with something. If you can, please help and thank you.

Comment: Note: You can't apply Titu because you didn't check if $a+c-b, a+b -c > 0$, which they need not be. $\quad$ If you further assume that $a, b, c$ are the sides of a triangle, then yes we can apply Titu, and you can complete via the rearrangement inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to complete from OP's approach. Notice that in order to apply Titu's lemma, we must check that the terms are positive, but they need not be in this setup. We'd use a variant of Titu's lemma, which is an immediate corollary of Titu's lemma.

> For real (not necessarily positive) numbers $a_i$ and positive reals $b_i$, we have
> $$\sum \frac{ a_i^2 } { b_i } \geq \frac { (\sum a_i)^2 } { b_i }. $$
> Proof: Titu's Lemma gives us $\sum \frac{ a_i^2 } { b_i } \geq \frac { (\sum |a_i|)^2 } { \sum b_i } $, and it's obvious that $\frac { (\sum |a_i|)^2 } { \sum b_i } \geq \frac{ (\sum a_i)^2 } { \sum b_i}$.

Applying this, we may correctly conclude as OP did that

$$LHS \geq \sum \frac{ 2a^2 } { b+c}.$$

Then, $ \{a^2, b^2, c^2 \}$ is similarly ordered with $ \{a, b, c \}$, oppositely ordered with $ \{ (a+b+c) -a, (a+b+c) - b, (a+b+c) - c \} $, and hence similarly ordered with $ \{ \frac{1}{b+c}, \frac{1}{c+a}, \frac{1}{a+b} \}$. Hence by the rearrangement inequality, the product is maximized when we take $(a^2, b^2, c^2 ) \cdot ( \frac{1}{b+c}, \frac{1}{c+a}, \frac{1}{a+b})$ vs any other arrangement, thus we get that $ \sum \frac{a^2}{b+c} \geq \sum \frac{b^2}{b+c}$ and also  $ \sum \frac{a^2}{b+c} \geq \sum \frac{b^2}{b+c}$.

Hence $ LHS \geq \sum \frac{ 2a^2}{b+c} \geq \sum \frac{ b^2+c^2}{b+c} $.

Equality holds iff $a=b=c$.

Comment: Splendid use of the rearrangement inequality. Any site or pdf where I can look more into it ? I'm not much used to it , which is why the inequality went over my head when I was trying to solve it myself, until you posted this.

Comment: Also why does , _oppositely ordered_ help you that much in the rearragement inequality when you state in the first line WLOG a>b. It would be intuitive that $\frac{2a^2}{b+c} \ge \frac{2b^2}{b+c}$.

Comment: @FabDust I made a bunch of edits. $\quad$ Give [this](https://brilliant.org/wiki/rearrangement-inequality/) a try.  $\quad$ Note that the sequences are actually similarly ordered. $\quad$ While you have it for the $a$ and $b$ variant (while assuming that $a \geq b \geq c$, we DO NOT get $ \frac{ 2c^2} { a+b} \geq \frac{2a^2}{a+b}$, hence cannot immediately draw the conclusion. Rearrangement inequality allows us to easily work around this.

Answer (score 1):

We need to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{(b+c-a)^2}{a}-a\right)\geq\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a^2+b^2}{a+b}-\frac{a+b}{2}\right)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{(b+c-2a)(b+c)}{a}\geq\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a-b)^2}{2(a+b)}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{(c-a-(a-b))(b+c)}{a}\geq\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a-b)^2}{2(a+b)}$$  or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a-b)\left(\frac{a+c}{b}-\frac{b+c}{a}\right)\geq\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a-b)^2}{2(a+b)}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a-b)^2(a+b+c)}{ab}\geq\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a-b)^2}{2(a+b)}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2\left(\frac{a+b+c}{ab}-\frac{1}{2(a+b)}\right)\geq0,$$ which is obvious.